# Where are Mail.app rules stored? They got deleted and I want to restore them

Tags: macos, email, mail-rules

Since Mail.app had trouble connecting to the various accounts, I tried to 'reset' it by removing all accounts and the stored passwords in Keychain Access.app. Then I re-added all the mail accounts.

However, for some reason all configured **rules** were deleted too, even though they are not directly tied to a specific mail account.

#### Where are these rules stored so that I can restore them from a time machine backup?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rules are stored in a property list at:

```
~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/SyncedRules.plist
```

1. Restore this file from a backup.
2. Restart Mail.app.
3. Re-enable the rules.

These days check for a V3 folder (El Capitan). Restoring only the `SyncedRules.plist` may not work as another .plist file indexes the active state of the current rules set. What worked here was to go back to an earlier version of the `~Library/Mail/V3/MailData` directory *(note that it is in the V3 directory-- not the V2 directory)*. This takes a few minutes as Mail has to re-import your messages, but it did restore rules which were not restored by restoring the just the `~/Library/Mail/V3/MailData/SyncedRules.plist` file only.

Comment: in El Capitan, I’ve discovered that this file is at `~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~mail/Data/V3/MailData/ubiquitous_SyncedRules.plist`.

`~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~mail/Data/V4/SyncedRules.plist` also exists, but is not as recent for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an update to Charles great answer to restore lost Apple Mail Rules which you might lose when upgrading to Mac High Sierra OS10.13.4:

1. Close Apple Mail. Probably on your iPhone and iPad too.
2. On your Mac, go to iCloud and uncheck the Mail box so you don't replace the corrupted file from iCloud when reopening Mail.
3. Go to an uncorrupted backup copy of Mail. Drill down in your User folder:
   ~/Library/Mail/V5/MailData/
   be sure it's the V5 folder, then open it, find and copy the SyncedFilesInfo.plist file. Soon you will see it's older and bigger than the corrupted new file.
4. Now go to your current hard drive and drill down to the same User folder:
   ~/Library/Mail/V5/MailData/
   then open it, find and delete the newer smaller SyncedFilesInfo.plist file and replace it with your older, bigger backup file.
5. Now, reopen Mail. Your recovered rules should be there. Go to your Preferences>Rules and activate your rules by checking all the desired boxes. Add or delete a rule just to be sure the file updates itself. If that didn't work, repeat with an older backup file.
6. Now close Apple Mail, open iCloud Preferences in the OS, recheck the "Mail" box and close iCloud. Life should be all good again.

---

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem under Mail V2 (Yosemite).  Deleting `SyncedRules.plist` did not work ; the same rules kept coming back when Mail was restarted.

This is due to the rules being synced on iCloud.  To prevent that:

- Quit Mail.
- Edit `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/SyncedFilesInfo.plist` and delete the entry corresponding to `SyncedRules.plist`.
- Recover `SyncedRules.plist` from your backup.
- Restart Mail and re-enable the rules.

Your recovered rules should now be there.

-- Charles

Answer (score 0):

Since this stuff gave me a headache, i want to share my personal experience from V4. 
Make sure, you delete the `SynchedRules.plist` in this directory, too:
`~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~mail/Data/V4/SyncedRules.plist`

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a modification of Longmont Ron’s update of Charles’ answer that doesn’t require actually editing the `SyncedRules.plist` file:

1. Quit Mail.app on your Mac
2. Recover old, uncorrupted versions (e.g., from Time Machine) of `SyncedRules.plist` and `SyncedFilesInfo.plist`
3. In the iCloud pane of System Preferences, disable both the main Mail checkbox and, under the Options button next to iCloud Drive, the Mail checkbox there as well (this second-level-down checkbox turned out to be crucial in my experience)
4. Replace the corrupted versions of both files in `~/Library/Mail/V5/MailData/`
5. Relaunch Mail.app and your rules should be back in place (though they may need to be re-enabled — you can option-click one checkbox to toggle them all back on)
6. Back in the iCloud pane of System Preferences, re-enable both the main Mail checkbox and, under the Options button next to the iCloud Drive, the Mail checkbox there also

Answer (score 0):

Having similar issues with my two Mac platforms, an M1 2021 iMac with macOS 13.1 Ventura, and a 2014 MacBook Pro with macOS 11.7.2, Big Sur.

Under 11.7.2 The path to the Rules plist is: `~/Library/Mail/V8/MailData/SyncedRules.plist`
Under 13.1.0 The path to the Rules plist is: `~/Library/Mail/V10/MailData/SyncedRules.plist`

In my case, the M1 iMac is the “main computer”. It has a more up-to-date set of Mail Rules.   Based on the above guides, I found my way to the rules.plist file.

I copied the iMac plist file to a thumb drive.  From the thumb drive, I copied the .plist file to the proper location in the MacBookPro.

I rebooted the MacBook Pro, opened Mail, and verified the replaced .plist file was in fact delivering the rules as it had done on the iMac.

SUCCESS.It worked! I thought I'd share.